# Is there a way to rearrange columns of repeating sections in the exported CSV file?

Tags: cognito-forms, export, csv

I am using Cognito Forms to gather information about my worker's work progress for client billing purposes. They submit one form a day, but each work assignment gets filled out in a repeating section.  The data doesn't come out in the most logical way, so I would like to be able to rearrange the layout of the columns when I export the CSV file so that I can more easily make sense of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

At the moment we do not have a way to reorder the fields in the Repeating Section before you export to Excel/CSV file.